# SOAP request and responce is not in XML

Tags: php, xml, soap

I have the following PHP code with SOAP

```
<?php
    $client = new SoapClient(null, array( 
        'location' => 'http://www.adler.info/b2bsoap.php', 
        'uri' => 'http://test-uri/', 
        'trace' => true, 
        'stream_context' => true, 
        'exceptions'=> false, 
        'login' => 'myname', 
        'password' => 'password' 
    ));

    $result= $client->stock(array('format'=>'xml', 'structure'=>'complex'));
    echo "REQUEST HEADERS:\n" . $client->__getLastRequestHeaders() . "\n";
    echo '<BR />---------------------------------------<BR />';
    echo "REQUEST:\n" . $client->__getLastRequest() . "\n";
    echo '<BR />---------------------------------------<BR />';
    echo "Response:\n" . $client->__getLastResponse() . "\n";
?>
```

This is the output:

```
REQUEST HEADERS: POST /b2bsoap.php HTTP/1.1 Host: www.adler.info Connection: Keep-Alive User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/5.6.0 Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8 SOAPAction: "http://test-uri/#stock" Content-Length: 716 Authorization: Basic MWFkbGVyOkFkbWluc2R6cA==
---------------------------------------
REQUEST: formatxmlstructurecomplex
---------------------------------------
Response: nomenid_nomen0100000000000001number1000008deliverydate2014-11-12count9666id_nomen0100000000000002number1000009deliverydate2014-11-12count14210... (it's longer, but the same type)
```

I'd like to have the SOAP response in XML format. But as you can see, this is only plain no formated text. But I don't understand it, because in the header you can see Content-Type: text/xml.

What should I do to have a response in the XML format?
Thank you!

Comment: And you copy/pasted the result from your browser window? did you do a view source?

Comment: Yes this is from my browser. How to view the source? I must admit that SOAP is new for me from today. I have never heard about it before. But I must do it for my job.

Comment: If you would view the page source in your browser window. You will see the actual XML response. So looks like everything is working just fine.

Comment: Oh.. I'm stupid. You thought html source...

Comment: Write it please as an answer so I can mark it as useful and solve my problem. ;)